# Adding arrows to pairs plot

Tags: r, pca

I am doing principal component analysis. I got the `pairs` plot of PC components. However, I want to visualize all the plots. PC1 vs PC2, PC2 vs PC3, etc. I got 8 components. Is there a way I can add the arrows to the PC `pairs` plot? My plot looks like below. I want to add arrows with rotation to each of the pairs in order to understand which grouping is better. I have used `prcomp` funtion to compute the principal components. I have loadings and rotations saved in separate extracts as well. Kind of stuck here as how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: The `pairs` function (from which this appears to be the output) is _not_ part of ggplot2 pkg. (So I removed that tag as well as correcting function name spellings) You would need base plotting functions advice to accomplish this task. And _as_ _always_ a [MCVE] is needed for coding advice.